# Generating a sequence in R

Tags: r

I am working with a list in R that looks like this

```
[1] 0 0 4 4 0 4 0
```

now suppose that I want to generate a list of numbers corresponding to this list like this

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 2 2

[[3]]
[1] 3 6

[[4]]
[1] 7 10

[[5]]
[1] 11 11

[[6]]
[1] 12 15

[[7]]
[1] 16 16
```

So in other words, the first list gives the groups of a list of a sequence of numbers from 1 to 16 and the second list gives the start and end of each group.

This is probably easier to see if you consider the sequence

1 2 3-6 7-10 11 12-15 16

Is there an easy way to do this?  I think I could do it using some sort of global index and lapply but I wanted to see if there were an easier way.

Comment: pretty sure 1 1 4 4 1 4 1 makes more sense than zeros there...

Comment: There are zeros because of the formatting required for the output.

Comment: Sorry, the [[17]] was a typo, fixed now.  Also that is just the non-R way of understanding the sequence.

Comment: Try `v2 <- replace(v1, !v1, 1); Map('c',  cumsum(v2)-v2+1, cumsum(v2))`

Comment: Akrun, amazing.  Can you put that as the answer?  Thanks

Comment: @rdevn00b I think it is  just another variety of Frank's answer.

Comment: Also, what exactly is your code doing Akrun?

Comment: I replaced the 0 values with 1.  For the first element of each list, I subtracted the cumulative sum from the modified vector to get the starting position.  For the second I just did the `cumsum`

Comment: @akrun I've added it to my answer. Thanks. Feel free to edit

Comment: I'm not sure who downvoted the question, but this is a sequence problem that is typical when working when applying density functions to sequences of numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way

```
# alternate input suggested by @MichaelChirico
d = c(0,0,3,3,0,3,0)

# my preferred approach
library(data.table) # version 1.9.5+
Map(c, 
  seq_along(d)+shift(cumsum(d), type="lag", fill=0),
  seq_along(d)+cumsum(d)
)
```

A similar variation by @akrun:

```
# alternate input, starting from OP's
d2 = c(0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 4, 0)
d2 = replace( d2, !d2, 1)

# @akrun's answer
Map(c, cumsum(d2)-d2+1, cumsum(d2))
```

And some more:

```
# my original answer
start = c(1,head(cumsum(d+1)+1,-1))
Map(c, start, start + d)

# another way
s = sequence(d+1)
Map(c, seq_along(s)[s==1], seq_along(s)[c(diff(s) < 1, TRUE)] )
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly different approach:

```
x <-  c(0,0,3,3,0,3,0)

f <- function(x) {
    ee <- split(seq_len(sum(x+1)), rep.int(seq_along(x), x+1))
    lapply(ee, range)
}
f(x)
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that'll do it, no way near as elegant as @Frank's answer:

```
mygenerator <- function(vec){
  counter <- 1
  outlist <- list()
  for(i in 1:length(vec)){
    if(vec[i] == 0){
      outlist[[i]] <- c(counter, counter)
      counter <- counter + 1
    } else {
      outlist[[i]] <- c(counter, counter + vec[i] - 1)
      counter <- counter + vec[i]
    }
  }
  outlist
}

mygenerator(c(0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 4, 0))

[[1]]
[1] 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 2 2

[[3]]
[1] 3 6

[[4]]
[1]  7 10

[[5]]
[1] 11 11

[[6]]
[1] 12 15

[[7]]
[1] 16 16
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.